# After compressing the video, it's quality getting dull in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, video, ffmpeg, compression

I have done with the video compressing using ffmpeg in Android and I am having some problem in it.

I have captured one video of exactly one minute and it has 123 MB of size on my nexus 5. I did video compressing of the same video from 123 MB to 1.30 MB approx and it will take 2 minutes near about and that was successfully done.

**But the question is that I have the compressed video in my SD Card and when I'll play it, the quality of the video is totally dull, below is my code using ffmpeg.**

```
String[] complexCommand = {"ffmpeg", "-i", videoPath, "-strict","experimental","-s", "160x120","-r","25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b", "150k", "-ab","48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", demoVideoFolder + "Compressed_Video.mp4"};

LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
            try {
                 vk.run(complexCommand, workFolder, getApplicationContext(),
                 false);
                GeneralUtils.copyFileToFolder(vkLogPath, demoVideoFolder);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e(Prefs.TAG, "vk run exeption.", e);
            } finally {
                if (wakeLock.isHeld())
                    wakeLock.release();
                else {
                    Log.i(Prefs.TAG,
                            "Wake lock is already released, doing nothing");
                }
            }
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "doInBackground finished");
```

Here **videopath** is my filepath and **demofolder** is my output folder. I have attached the snapshot, just have a look into it.

[image]

Please, tell me what I should do, so just in advance your efforts will be highly appreciated and thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Dull" is very subjective, I really don't know what to make of that. If you have specific artifacts you want to discuss, please post screenshots. I can make some general comments on your commandline that may or may not be helpful:

- -s 160x120 - are we back in 1995? This is what we used to refer to when we said "stamp-sized video" in the mid-90s. In case you didn't know, this resizes the video to a resolution of 160x120, which destroys quality.
- -r 25 you're dropping and adding frames at random here. You most likely want to use a fps filter, or remove this option altogether.
- -vcodec mpeg4 - people use H.264 nowadays (-vcodec libx264), if not HEVC/VP9 (-vcodec libx265/libvpx-vp9).
- -b 150k - this is a very low bitrate. If you don't like the video quality, please increase the bitrate.
- -strict experimental - don't use this unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Hey, I have attached an image file on my asked question, just have a look to it, so you can get the overall idea.

Comment: resolution is too low, remove the -s 160x120 or set it to something higher.

Comment: Ya, its done, and I have removed that part. But before that the file size should be near about 2.60 and after removing that code the file size should be near about 9 MB, little bit high.

Comment: Well yeah, better quality typically means higher file size. If you want better compression (quality/filesize tradeoff), try a newer codec (e.g. -vcodec libx264 for H.264 encoding).